# How do I get the COM object from a HWND in Win32::OLE?

Tags: perl, winapi, ole

In Perl, if I have HWND of a window object, how can I get access to that COM object using that handle? I looked at Win32::OLE but the closest I got was the `GetActiveObject` method, which expects a class.

Comment: I am using AutoIt to include some win32 app automation in our extensively Perl automation framework. AutoIt conveniently provides activex control to access it through any language & that is what I am using. Now, for attaching to existing application instances like IE, AutoIt already has native scripts for it but I am trying to replicate that in Perl. 

One of the methods that AutoIt provides is ControlGetHandle, which will give you HWND of an existing instance of a specific app window that you are interested in. But nowI need access to its COM object. Hope that clears up what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard way to obtain a COM interface pointer from an HWND, because a window is not a COM object.  The basic Windows API, including window handles, predates the invention of OLE and COM.  The implementation of a particular window may expose some or all of its functionality through COM interfaces, but those interfaces will be application-specific.

If it is documented that the window you want to control exposes a public COM interface, the documentation for that window will also tell you how to query the window for an interface pointer.  Most likely, it will require sending an application-specific [window message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632590(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

#### Get an HWND or location from an Accessible Object and manipulate it with the Windows API:

```
use Win32::GuiTest;
```

#### use a HWND

```
my $hwnd = $ao->WindowFromAccessibleObject();
my $name = Win32::GuiTest::GetWindowText($hwnd);
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I think this leads me in right direction, I'll read the doc to see if I can get the pointer to the COM object. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get the IAccessible interface from an HWND, you can try using [WM_GETOBJECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373892(VS.85).aspx) (note: I assume there is someway to send window messages in Perl—it is well established that I have no Perl knowledge).

Not everyone does it this way, so make sure you handle failure somehow.  For example, Internet Explorer exposes [WM_HTML_GETOBJECT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q249232/) to get the IHTMLDocument2 pointer.